# Gradle build failed. Cannot build gradle due to error

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, build.gradle

when running gradle init. I got a build failed error. The error is as follows:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.ApplicationVariantImpl.
      > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.
```

My gradle version is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-08-17 07:06:47 UTC
Revision:     8afbf24b469158b714b36e84c6f4d4976c86fcd5

Kotlin:       1.9.0
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          21 (Homebrew 21)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.1 aarch64
```

My java Version is:

```
openjdk version "17.0.8.1" 2023-08-24
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.8.1+1 (build 17.0.8.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.8.1+1 (build 17.0.8.1+1, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Namespace not specified - add the namespace to your build.gradle 
namespace "com.yourcompany.yourapp"

Comment: how do I specify my namepsace?

Comment: build.gradle after the plugin -------- plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
 
// Add this line for the namespace
namespace "com.example.myapp"

Comment: is this for the project build.gradle file or the app file

Comment: build.gradle file

Comment: I added the plugin code with buildscript but it says it could not find the method

Comment: create a new project with android studio that will give you an example of how the build.gradle should look like

Comment: Thanks. I'll let you know how that goes

Comment: i'm currently having this problem. Could not find method plugins() for arguments [build_6wuyka07q46lf20w9ig8ghjtr$_run_closure1$_closure4@3cc0080d] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.